# How to efficiently select distinct tags with associated items in many-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, taxonomy

I'm building a system that has items and tags, with a many-to-many relationship (via an intermediate table), in MySQL. As I've scaled it up, one query has become unacceptably slow, but I'm struggling to make it more efficient.

The query in question amounts to "**select all tags that have an item of type x associated with them**". Here's a very slightly simplified version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t.id)
FROM tags t 
INNER JOIN items_tags it ON it.tag_id = t.id
INNER JOIN items i ON it.item_id = i.id
WHERE i.type = 10
```

I have unique primary indexes on `t.id`, `item.id` and "`it.tag_id, it.item_id`". The problem I'm having is that the items_tags table is at a size (~1,400,000 rows) where the query takes too long (one thing that puzzles me here is that phpMyAdmin seems to think the query is fast - it times it as a few ms, but in practice it seems to take 6 or 7 seconds).

It feels to me as if there might be a way of joining the items_tags table to itself to reduce the size of the result set (and perhaps remove the need for that DISTINCT clause), but I can't figure out how... Alternatively, it occurs to me that there might be a better way of indexing things. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Given that there are no columns coming from `tags` except for `id` you can eliminate `tags` entirely and get the values from `items_tags.tag_id`.

Comment: That's a very good point! This is actually a slightly simplified version of my full query (I actually fetch tag name too), but it turns out that leaving the tag table out and then treating the above as a subquery (which I join the tag table onto) is significantly faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the record, here's what worked for me (though I'd still be interested if anyone has any other suggestions).

It was pointed out (in the comments above - thanks @Turophile!) that since tag id is available in the `items_tags` table, I could leave the `tags`  table out. I actually did need other fields (eg. name) from the tags table (I simplified the query a little for the question), but I found that removing the tags table from the above query and joining the tags table onto its results was significantly faster (`EXPLAIN` showed that it allowed fewer rows to be scanned). That made the query look more like this:

```
SELECT 
    tags.id,
    tags.name
FROM tags 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(it.tag_id) AS tag_id
    FROM items_tags it
    JOIN items i ON it.item_id = i.id
    WHERE i.type = 10 
) it ON tags.id = it.tag_id
```

This was about 10x faster than the previous version of the query (reduced the average time from about 27s to ~2.5s).

On top of that, adding an index to `items.type` improved things further (reduced the average time from ~2.5s to ~1.2s).

Comment: Some databases/statements perform better when the `WHERE i.type = 10` is instead put onto the `ON` clause (the reason being that the rows are filtered out before the join is done whereas `WHERE` filters them after the join).

Comment: Thanks again - another interesting tip. I ran an `EXPLAIN` on the above statement and the version that uses `ON` instead of `WHERE`, and I got exactly the same result, so I'm guessing the DB I'm using (MySQL 5.6) treats the two approaches as equivalent, and perhaps adopts the faster approach (probably the one you suggest) as an optimisation step anyway. Still good to know about the `ON` clause though!